# Determine the convergence or divergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was studying calculus and found this question I tried to solve it using the ratio test but I get $1$ which means no conclusion.

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{\log_3(n)}}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The series is not well-defined, since the general term has no sense for $n=0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that, as @TheSilveDoe wrote, the series has no meaning for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$, suppose your series starts from $2$, then we can write:

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{\log_3(n)}} \equiv \sum_{n = 2}^{+\infty} \sqrt[\log_3(n)]{2}$$

We can use the limit test to study $\sum_n a_n$ as follows: its convergence can be determined by studying the limit as $k = \lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n$ with the following comparison:

- If $|k| > 0$ or $k$ is undefined, then the series diverges.
- if $k = 0$ the test is inconclusive.

We can apply it here, seeing that

$$k = \lim_{n\to +\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{log_3(n)}} = 1$$ hence $|1| > 0$ hence the series diverges.